# Pafy module causing error in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, youtube-dl, pafy

I am using pafy in a Flask app. It is working fine on my local machine. But when I am trying to deploy and run on PythonAnywhere, it is throwing an error. Upon execution, it is showing the following ewrror:

> youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: Unable to download API page: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden> (caused by URLError(OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
> **NO MATCH**
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> **NO MATCH**
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/Philomath/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 40, in _fetch_basic
> self._ydl_info = ydl.extract_info(self.videoid, download=False)
> File "/home/Philomath/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
> return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
> File "/home/Philomath/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 824, in wrapper
> self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
> File "/home/Philomath/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 628, in report_error
> self.trouble(error_message, tb)
> File "/home/Philomath/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 598, in trouble
> raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
> youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to download API page: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden> (caused by URLError(OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

I have also removed the lines for dislike count in backend_yoututbe_dl in PythonAnywhere (from bash). Still, no use.

Comment: Are you sure it's working fine on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. I have tested several times on my local machine. It is working perfectly.

Comment: Make sure that you are using full URL of the youtube videos

Comment: I don't think there will be any difference for that

Comment: The error message suggests that there is a problem with accessing the YouTube API page such as network connectivity issues or restrictions on the server you are running the app on.

Comment: According to the question, the server is PythonAnywhere

Comment: Check if there are any network restrictions or firewalls that might be blocking the connection to the YouTube API, Update `youtube_dl` to the last version or try using a different library for downloading videos from YouTube, such as `pytube`.

Comment: @George yes I am using PythonAnywhere.

Comment: @Sullivan I need to stream the video. If I am not mistaken, Pytube downloads the video in a file.

Comment: if with `pytube` you are able to download from youtube then `youtube_dl` has a problem

Comment: you can use `pytube` for stream the video

Comment: @Sullivan using VLC?

Comment: @Phil Yes you can using VLC for stream the video

Comment: @Sullivan I need to stream the video inside **video** tag in webpage. I used flask to get the URL and pass the stream as parameter inside the **video** tag. Can I achieve the same using Pytube?

Comment: @Phil you can get stream link with this code`from pytube import YouTube yt = YouTube(f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}') stream_url = yt.streams.first().url`

Comment: sorry for the bad format

Comment: I tried using Pytube. It is working fine in local machine but causing a similar issue in Flask.
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden
**NO MATCH**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will not work on PythonAnywhere. Any youtube video downloads use unofficial methods and so PythonAnywhere will not add youtube to the allowlist for free accounts.